# Bash: how to put each line of a column below the same-row-line of another column?

Tags: bash, dataframe, grep, row, multiple-columns

I'm working with some data using bash and I need that this kind of input file:

```
Col1  Col2
A      B
C      D
E      F
G      H
```

Turn out in this output file:

```
Col1
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

I tried with some commands but they didn't work. Any kind of suggestions will be very appreciated!

Comment: Please post the commands that didn’t work.

Comment: How are the columns separated? By a single tab character or by a sequence of space(s) and/or tab(s) ?

Comment: Theay are separated by one space

Comment: Use `tr` to replace the space with newline.

Comment: `sed '1s/ .*//; y/ /\n/' file` should do the trick if there is at most one space character per line.

Comment: does your real file contain *only* 2 columns? can any column contaion white space within a value (ie, do we need to maintain some spaces while replacing other spaces with a newline)?

Comment: Thank you everyone! Your suggestions have been very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many problems, there are many solutions.  Here is one using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $1; print $2}' inputfile.txt
```

The `NR > 1` expression says to execute the following block for all line numbers greater than one.  (NR is the current *record* number which is the same as line number by default.)

The `{print $1; print $2}` code block says to print the first field, then print the second field.  The advantage of using `awk` in this case is that it doesn't matter if the fields are separated by space characters, tabs, or a combination; the fields just have to be separated by some number of whitespace characters.

If the field values on each line are only separated by a single space character, then this would work:

```
tail -n +2 inputfile.txt | tr ' ' '\n'
```

In this solution, `tail -n +2` is used to print all lines starting with the second line and `tr ' ' '\n'` is used to replace all the space characters with newlines, as suggested by previously.

Comment: Most `tr` implementations have the squeeze (`-s`) option, so `tr -s ' ' '\n'` would work with multiple spaces

Comment: Good point.  It wouldn't handle a mix of tabs and spaces, but multiple spaces would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed explanation! The awk command was the best solution to solve my problem!

Comment: @GregBarrett: Sure it will, e.g. `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'

Comment: @Thor – Again I stand corrected, I had forgotten that character classes could be used.